# Why is an iphone's UUID required when using it as a test device in xcode?

Tags: ios, uuid

I'm just curious as to why it's needed... and am wondering if it can be tracked. For instance, if I sell my phone would someone else be able to know that device was used to test apps somehow?

Comment: Reset the device before selling, and remove it from test device list, and nobody will know that it was used for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actually you just have to delete it from your Test devices list. The UDID is just used when you sign the IPA to some specific test devices. It's a security mesure, because if it doesn't exist everybody could create apps and distribute them with out sign (Against Apple rules).